# jQuery Mobile Autocomplete search after 3 letters?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, autocomplete

Hy ,

I'm making a website and i have an autocomplete field.
  The problem is that i have 1000+ `<li>`s in that `<ul>` and on mobile it is very slow.
  I would like to make the filter after 3 letters.

I have this code :

```
jQuery(document).bind('pageinit' , function( event, data ){
 jQuery('input[data-type="search"]').listview('option', 'filterCallback',  yourFilterFunction);
 yourFilterFunction = function( text, searchValue ){
 if (searchValue.length < 3) { // automatically omit search terms less than 3 
  return 0;
 }
 return text.toLowerCase().indexOf( searchValue ) === -1;
 };
});
```

How can i make the options to show after 3 letters?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer

```
jQuery(document).bind('pageinit' , function( event, data ) {
 yourFilterFunction = function( text, searchValue ) {
  if (searchValue.length < 3) { // automatically omit search terms less than 3
   return -1;
  }
  return text.toLowerCase().indexOf( searchValue ) === -1;
 };
 jQuery("#business_list_id").listview('option', 'filterCallback', yourFilterFunction);
});
```

Comment: you can replace `jQuery` with `$`.